# What is difference between "gray" and "grey"?

Tags: synonyms

I want to ask what the difference beetween "gray" and "grey" as the color names?

Is there a difference like that one might be adjective, and the other one might be name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is entirely a matter of style. Here is what Wikipedia says:

> "The first recorded use of *grey* as a color name in the English language was in AD 700. *Grey* is the dominant spelling in European and Commonwealth English, although *gray* remained in common usage in the UK until the second half of the 20th century. *Gray* has been the preferred American spelling since approximately 1825, although *grey* is an accepted variant" ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grey)).

See also [here](http://www.greyorgray.com/).

That being said, a study in 1893 for what-would-become the OED revealed that *some* people used the terms with subtly different meanings:

> Interestingly some correspondents used both forms [*grey* and *gray*] but with a difference of meaning: 'the distinctions most generally recognized being that *grey* denotes a more delicate or lighter tint than *gray*. Others considered the difference to be that '*gray* is a "warmer" colour or that it has a mixture of red or brown' (*OED* under *grey*). This might possible be explained as a transfer of sound associations to letters ([here](https://books.google.com/books?id=jy_bCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA407&lpg=PA407&dq=artist%20who%20differentiated%20grey%20from%20gray&source=bl&ots=mug1sOJHlf&sig=FW6xl3ikpk6ULcVQI9UioRYKDMY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZl7OY2qLNAhUE5iYKHZddD-cQ6AEIRTAG#v=onepage&q=artist%20who%20differentiated%20grey%20from%20gray&f=false))